# Help with UITableView and NSArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to create a really simple to do list using an array and a tableview. When the user hits the + button, the insert method is called and a UIAlert is presented so the user can input text. Nothing crashes, but after the user hits OK, nothing is added to the tableview, however the log does display the code it's supposed to. Can anyone detect what's wrong? (I think I've made all the right connections in IB as well)

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {   
    data=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [data count];

}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if(cell==nil)
        cell=[[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"]autorelease];
    cell.textLabel.text=[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

-(IBAction)insert {
    UIAlertView* dialog = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];
    [dialog setDelegate:self];
    [dialog setTitle:@"Enter Name"];
    [dialog setMessage:@" "];
    [dialog addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
    [dialog addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];

    UITextField *nameField = [[UITextField alloc] 
                              initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0, 45.0, 245.0, 25.0)];
    [nameField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [dialog addSubview:nameField];
    [nameField release];
    [dialog show];
    [dialog release];
}


- (void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{       
    if (buttonIndex != 0)  // 0 == the cancel button
    {
        //  Since we don't have a pointer to the textfield, we're
        //  going to need to traverse the subviews to find our 
        //  UITextField in the hierarchy
        for (UIView* view in alertView.subviews)
        {
            if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
            {
                UITextField* textField = (UITextField*)view;
                [data addObject:textField.text == nil ? @"moha" : textField.text];
                NSLog(@"text:[%@]", textField.text);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
-(IBAction)toggleEdit {
    UIBarButtonItem *leftItem;
    [mainTableView setEditing:!mainTableView.editing animated:YES];

    if (mainTableView.editing) {
        leftItem=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(toggleEdit)];
    }else {
        leftItem=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit target:self action:@selector(toggleEdit)];
    }

    navItem.leftBarButtonItem=leftItem;

}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [data removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to force the tableview to reload its data after modifying the array:

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: Except it should be just `[mainTableView reloadData];`